# Is this a convergent integral or when it is?

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

What are the conditions for the integral given below to be convergent?
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{-t}\left(1+x\right)^{-a}\ dx
$$
where $a>0$. This is a simplified form of an integral. I want to
express this integral with summation symbol using binomial series
on the term $\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{-t}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{t+k}\tbinom{-t}{k}e^{kx}$
. Is it possible or is there stg wrong with this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide your problem into subproblems and analyse each case..

- $t < 0$: let $\beta = -t \to \beta > 0$
  $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{-t}\left(1+x\right)^{-a}\ dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{\beta}}{\left(1+x\right)^{a}}\ dx\\ = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{\beta}}{\left(1+x\right)^{a}}\ dx + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{\beta}}{\left(1+x\right)^{a}}\ dx$$
  and since the first integral is bounded and positive, while the second diverges, the case when $t < 0$ makes the whole starting integral divergent
- $t=0$: the integral can be reduced to
  $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{a}}\ dx = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{a}}\ dx$$
  which is convergent $\iff a > 1$
- $t>0$: divide the integral as before, then you get $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{t} \cdot \left(1+x\right)^{a}}\ dx + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{t} \cdot \left(1+x\right)^{a}}\ dx$$
  now, examine the two integrals:

  - the second one, namely $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{t} \cdot \left(1+x\right)^{a}}\ dx$, is stricly less than $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{t} \cdot x^{a}}\ dx = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{t+a}}\ dx$ and it's convergent when $t+a > 1$
  - the first one, $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{t} \cdot \left(1+x\right)^{a}}\ dx$ converges $\iff \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{t}}\ dx$ converges, since $\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{a}}$ is a rational number (and so bounded by some constant $C$) in $[0;1]$. But a simple substitution suggests us that the first integral converges only when $t < $: in fact by letting $e^x - 1 = y$, and then $y = \frac{1}{z}$ you get 
    $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{t}}\ dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y^{t}} \cdot \frac{1}{y+1}\ dy < \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y^{t}}\ dy = \int_{0}^{1}z^t \cdot -\frac{1}{z^2}\ dz = -\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{2-t}}\ dz$$ which converges $\iff 2-t > 1 \iff t < 1$

  Finally the conditions for the convergence are
  $$\begin{cases}
  0 < t < 1\\
  0 < a\\
  a + t > 1
  \end{cases}$$
  but the third one is trivial and it's a consequence of the first two, so the only condition for the convergence of the integral when $t > 0$ is $t < 1$

In other words:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{-t}\left(1+x\right)^{-a}\ dx \quad \text{ converges when }
\begin{cases}
t < 0,  & \text{ never} \\
t = 0, & a > 1 \\
t > 0, & t < 1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: can you suggest me about binomial expansion please? Is there a mistake in the term $(−1)^{t+k}$?

Comment: you may need to expand the series as a McLaurin one, then check id the radius of convergence is $\infty$..